# Como registrar dll .net usando Inno Setup

Tags: c#, .net, instalador, inno-setup

Tenho uma DLL escrita em C# e não consigo registra-la utilizando o Inno Setup.

Um exemplo de como executar esse processo seria útil.

Comment: Pode postar como você tentou até o momento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize a seguinte sintaxe em seu script do Inno Setup:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{dotnet20}\Regasm.exe"; Parameters: "{nome da dll} /codebase"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden; StatusMsg: "Registrando DLL"
```

No lugar do código {dotnet20}, pode ser alterado para a versão do NET Framework em questão, por exemplo: {dotnet30}, {dotnet40}, {dotnet4.5}.

O parâmetro "WorkingDir" refere-se ao local onde está a respectiva dll.

Obviamente o NET Framework precisará estar instalado. Então este comando deve ser executado somente após a instalação do mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Um assembly (.dll) do .net precisa ser registrado de forma diferente das demais .dll's. O Inno Setup não saberá distinguir isso quando você marcar a .dll como `regserver`.

Neste caso, tente colocar no final do seu script (após a descompactação da instalação):

```
[Run]
Filename: "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe"; Parameters: "/codebase [CaminhoParaSuaDllAqui]"
```

*[(Baseado nesta resposta do SO Inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322353/how-to-register-net-assembly-as-com)*